# google geocode API returns wrong results for state codes

Tags: google-geocoding-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MA
The above url, with the api key returns below response
"formatted_address" : "Independence, KS 67301, USA",

I experienced same results in kansas and oklahoma for many state codes I tried. is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

We were having the issue to so I created an issue ticket with Google. Their response it that it is a feature not a bug"

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MD&language=en
>   returns Maryland, USA (ChIJ35Dx6etNtokRsfZVdmU3r_I).
>
> However, both MD and VA are, in a worldwide context, extremely
>   ambiguous, which is why the expected result is not guaranteed. Better
>   results can be expected using Component Filtering or Place
>   Autocomplete:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:VA|country:US
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=VA&types=(regions)&components=country:US